# Parsing site using HtmlAgilityPack in C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

For example, I have link https://shikimori.one/animes/38256-magia-record-mahou-shoujo-madoka-magica-gaiden-tv/art

I wanna get from there list of div classes by name "container packery" using HtmlAgilityPack in C#. (in order to download images from all the links) But this part

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(link);

var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(link);
```

return me html code from this page https://shikimori.one/animes/38256-magia-record-mahou-shoujo-madoka-magica-gaiden-tv as i understood. So, I can`t parse anything from "/art". That because next part of code just returns null.

```
var links = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            .Equals("menu-slide-outer x199")).ToList();
```

What am I missing?

Final code:

```
class Program
{

    static List<string> sources = new List<string>();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var link = "https://shikimori.one/animes/1577-taiho-shichau-zo/art";

        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.BrowserTimeout = TimeSpan.FromTicks(0);
        var htmlDocument = web.LoadFromBrowser(link);

        var divlink = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            .Equals("container packery")).ToList();

        var alink = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            .Equals("b-image")).ToList();

        foreach(var a in alink)
        {
            sources.Add(a.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `HttpClient`:

```
        string html = string.Empty;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(link);
        }

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html); // LoadHtml expects the page source, not the URL.
```

Or, a simple way to parse HTML code from a URL:

```
        var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        var htmlDocument = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(link);
```

Or, load dynamic (i.e. Ajax) content:

```
        var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        var htmlDocument = web.LoadFromBrowser(link);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a simple way to parse html code from URL?

Comment: Thank you, it`s working! But I ran into a new problem. When I try to get all from div block named "l-content", the result is actually all the div block to the end. But it is missing class "b-gallery" which contains all the image links. I assume that the client simply does not load the entire page when it is fully loaded. Is there way to load whole page?

Comment: @Okashi Not exactly, it's a script that runs to "load" the content, but HtmlAgilityPack can do that too. Updated.

Comment: It basically works. But its loading content idk, randomly? When I remove the [STAThread] or comment web.BrowserTimeout = TimeSpan.FromTicks(0), running the code, have an error, adding this things back, its sometimes working again. I can’t understand what the problem is. Added the final code in the question. It`s just loading as before, without full content.